# How to replace first number before a space in each line in a text file

Tags: python, replace, text-files

My file look like the following:

```
12.32 1:34 2:49 5:21 29:98
13.53 1:23 2:82 5:23 29:45
51.92 1:23 2:54 5:54 29:63
12.42 1:34 2:43 5:32 29:32
```

I am trying to replace every first number in each line by another number. So the output will be like

```
21.33 1:34 2:49 5:21 29:98
16.23 1:23 2:82 5:23 29:45
93.12 1:23 2:54 5:54 29:63
18.76 1:34 2:43 5:32 29:32
```

What would be a good method?

I tried pointing to the number  by

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    line[0]
```

but it just gives me first character, not the entire number.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi. It would be helpful if you have a concrete example of what your expected output is. Shall we replace the first number by 8? Also, do want the output printed out or written to another file?

Comment: Call `split()` to split the line into a list of words.

Comment: As you know how to get first char, then you must know how to get rest of the three numbers.

Comment: @Spinor8 So I would replace12.32, 16.23, 51.92, 12.42 with other numbers. Edited the question above. Thanks!

Comment: `words = line.split()`, then `words[0]` will be `12.32`.

Comment: Where are you getting the new numbers from? Another file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following method to achieve this:-

```py
data = None
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

def process_line_item(x):
    index = x[0]
    line_str = x[1]
    new_first_value = [str(x[0])] # you can put here new value depending on line index
    return ' '.join(new_first_value + x[1].split(' ')[1:])

new_data = '\n'.join(list(map(process_line_item, enumerate(data.split('\n')))))

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(new_data)
```

`file.txt`

```
12.32 1:34 2:49 5:21 29:98
13.53 1:23 2:82 5:23 29:45
51.92 1:23 2:54 5:54 29:63
12.42 1:34 2:43 5:32 29:32
```

`new_file.txt`

```
0 1:34 2:49 5:21 29:98
1 1:23 2:82 5:23 29:45
2 1:23 2:54 5:54 29:63
3 1:34 2:43 5:32 29:32
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module with `delimiter=" "`:

```
from csv import reader

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = reader(file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in csv_reader:
        row[0] = '??.??'
        print(row)
```

which outputs

```
['??.??', '1:34', '2:49', '5:21', '29:98']
['??.??', '1:23', '2:82', '5:23', '29:45']
...
```

note that your numbers will be strings. you may have to convert them to floats:

```
floats = [float(item) for item in row]
```

if you then need to write the changes to a file you could similarly use a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick, however it may be a bit faulty and may need tweaking and testing a bit. I hope it helps though.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_content = file.read()
    list_content = [letter for letter in file_content]
    num_length = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(list_content):
        num_length += 1
        if list_content[i - 1] == '\n':
            num_length = 0

        elif char == ' ':
            start_index = i - num_length
            for _ in range(num_length + 1):
                list_content.pop(start_index)

            list_content.insert(start_index, your_new_number)

    out_text = ''.join(list_content)

with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(out_text)
```